# Overflow div hardly able to pinch zoom on ipad

Tags: html, css, ipad, overflow, pinch

If I make a #viewport div wrapping a #wrapper div

```
    #viewport{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:scroll;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
   #wrapper{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;

    }

    <div id='viewport'>
       <div id='wrapper'>
       <!--Web Content Here -->
       </div>
    </div>
```

In Ipad it is can't be easily pinch zoom, you have to touch by 2 fingers statically without moving first on the screen for a second before it can pinch zoom, very inconvenience, any solution?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. It appears that if you move the first finger before touching with the second one, the viewport div starts scrolling, and from that point it stops reacting to the pinch events.
BTW this does not happen when the scroll is on the whole window.